# how to show multiple methods invoked when a soap service is invoked

Tags: php, soap, yii2-advanced-app

I want to call multiple methods in a soap service
Below is is my code

```
class TestController extends Controller {
    public function actions()
    {
       return [
          'GetService' => 'mongosoft\soapserver\Action',
      ];

}

/**
 * @soap
 */
public function GetMyService($a,$d)
{

}

public function GetMyService1($b,$d)
{} }
```

I want to list all the methods that is written inside GetService ie,  GetMyService($a,$b) and GetMyService1($b,$b) .please provide a solution for this issue

Comment: i want to get all the methods invoked when i execute that controller

Comment: When i execute GetService ,I want to list all the methods invoked in that class same sa that of asmx page